# using dotnet user-secrets to store a string list

Tags: dotnet-tool

how can i get to save this:

```
"myList" : [ "file", "something" ]
```

in dotnet user-secrets?

I can add this to user secrets with the command:

```
dotnet user-secrets set --id my-id myList "[ \"file\", \"something\" ]"
```

but this is saved as a string and doesnt behave the same as if read from the appsettings.json.

it appears to me that user secrets do not support json arrays.  is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly edit "user secrets" of your project. User secrets of a project are saved in  "secrets.json" file. The file location is here :

- In Windows : **%Appdata%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<guid>\secrets.json**
- In Linux: **~/.microsoft/usersecrets/<guid>/secrets.json**

***<guid>*** is basically GUID for your project's user secrets. you can see it in the .csproj file like this :

```
<UserSecretsId>16abe888-53cb-415c-9889-797efe87c422</UserSecretsId>
```

Here is a sample **secrets.json** file :

```
{
"UserSecretsConfig" : {
  "UserName1": "john.doe",
  "Password1": "pppp",
  "Domain": "company.local",
  "Uri": "https://google.com/",
  "ToEmails":["user1@example.com", "user2@example.com", "user3@example.com"]
  }
}
```

Here is model class for the sample user secrets :

```
  public class MyUserSecretsConfig
    {
        public string UserName1 { get; set; }
        public string Password1 { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string Uri { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> ToEmails { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is sample code for reading "user secrets" in a console app :

```
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddUserSecrets<Program>();

            var config = builder.Build();
            MyUserSecretsConfig mySecrets = config.GetSection("UserSecretsConfig")
                      .Get<MyUserSecretsConfig>();
```

In order the above shown code to work you have to add these packages to your project:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets

In addition, if you will be accessing user secrets in a ASP.NET Core application the Configuration
is available via Injection at Startup class. There is no need for ConfigurationBuilder.

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the effort in the reply.  I should have explained what I am trying to do.  I am using terraform to generate cloud resources and put the keys into my user secrets automatically.  this way i can write scripts along with my github samples that do not store any secrets, but have one line of installation to set everuthing up!  To do this i would need to be able to run the dotnet user-secrets command as above.  thanks again, but i opted for the lazy mans way out.  i didnt use a json collection in the config.  i changed it to a csav and i do the collection conversion in the code.....